# my picture won't resize tf.image.resize_with_padding tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tensorflow, image-processing

my original image is 600*600 px I want to resize it to be 300*300 px

**Resize code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.layers.image_preprocessing import ResizeMethod


def resize(image, w=300, h=300):

    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.asarray(image))
    size = (w, h)
    tf.image.resize_with_pad(
        image,
        h,
        w,
        method=ResizeMethod.BILINEAR
    )
    image = array_to_img(image)
    return image
```

After I save the image the dimensions do not change

**Save images code**

```
def write_images(images, path):
    try:
        index = 1
        for img in images:
            img.save(path+f'/{index}.jpeg')
            index += 1
    except:
        print('Error while writing images')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow operations are **not in place**. You need to assign the result of the resize operation as follows:

```
image = tf.image.resize_with_pad(
    image,
    h,
    w,
    method=ResizeMethod.BILINEAR
)
```

Comment: so every tf.image.* returns the value and doesn't update the image itself?